# cv2.imwrite not saving any image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to run a simple example code to write an image using opencv on python3. Code reference:[1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imwrite-method/)

```
import cv2
import os

image_path = r'C:\Users\840g1 touch\Desktop\B2.jpg'

directory = r'C:\Users\840g1 touch\Desktop'

img = cv2.imread(image_path)

os.chdir(directory)

print("Before saving image:")
print(os.listdir(directory))

# Filename
filename = 'savedImage.jpg'

cv2.imwrite(filename, img)

print("After saving image:")
print(os.listdir(directory))

print('Successfully saved')
```

Image is displaying and everything but the image is not getting saved anywhere. I am using Anaconda on windows. Not sure if the problem is related to the code or my PC.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: be sure that the image is loaded correctly, i.e. `img not None`

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a path for `imwrite` so it writes in your pythons *current working directory*.

change the line:

```
cv2.imwrite(filename, img)
```

to something like:

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(directory,filename), img)
```

note:
you can get your current working dir with

```
os.getcwd()
```

Comment: Still no luck. I tried the same code on a different system and it works fine.